# I want to create a Search method that autodisplay some results

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm creating a function that is looking for users in database.
I've done the server-side code, but I don't know how to display the results in the html code. I know that I have to write some JavaScript code but I don't know how

I found something on Google, but it doesn't work.

This is my route.

```
router.get('/search', isAuth, feedController.getSearch);
```

This is my controller.

```
exports.getSearch = (req,res,next) => {
    const search = req.query.searchField;

   User.find({
      firstname:{
          $regex: new RegExp(search)
      },
    }, {
        _id:0,
        __v:0
    }, function (err,data) {
        res.json(data);
    }
   ).limit(10);

}
```

This is my HTML

```
 <li>
                            <div class="search-box">
                              <form action="/search" method="GET" class="form-inline my-0 my-lg-0">
                              <input type="text" aria-label="Search" class="form-control mr-sm-0" onkeyup="showResults(this.value)" placeholder="Mirror-Mirror Search">
                              <span class="hightlight"></span>
                              <span class="bar"></span>
                              </input>
                              <button type="submit" class="search-btn"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>
                              </form>
                            </div>
                            <div style="position: relative; width:100%; top:-1px;">
                            <div class="border" id="search-results"></div>
                            </div>
                          </li>
```

And this is what I found on Google

```
var showResults = debounce(function(arg) {
    var value = arg.trim();
    if(value == "" || value.length <=0)
    {
        $("#search-results").fadeOut();
        return;
    }
    else {
        $("#search-results").fadeIn();
    }
    var jgxh = $.get('/controllers/feed/getSearch?searchField=' + value, function(data) {
        $("#search-results").html("");
    })
    .done(function(data){
        if(data.length === 0) {
            $("#search-results").append('<p class="lead text-center mt-2">No results</p>');
        } else {
            data.forEach(x => {
               $("#search-results").append('<a href="#> <p class="m-2 lead>' +x.firstname+' '+x.lastname + '</p></a>')
            });
        }
    })
    .fail(function(err){
        console.log(err);
    })
},200)
function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
    var timeout;
    return function() {
        var context = this;
        args = arguments;
        var later = function () {
            timeout = null;
            if(!immediate) func.apply(context,args);

        };
        var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout =  setTimeout(later, wait);
        if(callNow) func.apply(context,args);
    };
};
```

I expected to autodisplay the results, but It doesn't work. I want to search in my database either for 'firstname' or 'lastname', I hope you can help me, thank you!

Comment: What error is throwing in console?

Comment: I'm not home right now, but it throws something about the pathing to the my controller

Comment: Could you please tell me your UI framework

Comment: I'm using EJS, that guy worked with Handlebars